# How to reference an id value from another main.tf file residing in a different module in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Is there a way to reference an id value from another object located in a different main.tf file in a different module?

If the two resources or objects are located in the same file you just do this

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "log_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-tf-log-bucket"
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  logging {
    target_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.log_bucket.id
    target_prefix = "log/"
  }
}
```

You can assign the target_bucket for logging to the id of the bucket in `resource "aws_s3_bucket"`

Now suppose I have two folders named `log_module` and `s3_module` with their respective `main.tf` files.

The `main.tf` inside the log_module contains

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "log_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-tf-log-bucket"
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"
}
```

and the `main.tf` inside the s3_module contains

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  logging {
    target_bucket = "target-bucket"
    target_prefix = "log/"
  }
}
```

How would I assign the id for the bucket in `resource "aws_s3_bucket" "log_bucket"`
to the target_bucket in the `main.tf` for the s3_module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Terraform [output values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html) to achieve this functionality.

In your `log_module` directory, you can create a new file named `outputs.tf` and define a new output like so:

```
output "bucket_id" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.log_bucket.id
}
```

In your `s3_module`, you would need to create a [variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html) file (e.g., `variables.tf`) which would be used to assign a value to the `target_bucket` for the `aws_s3_bucket` resource.

For example:

```
variable "target_bucket" {
  description = "The name of the bucket that will receive the log objects"
  type        = string
}
```

Then you would modify the `main.tf` file in your `s3_module` directory like so:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  logging {
    target_bucket = var.target_bucket
    target_prefix = "log/"
  }
}
```

Where the value of `target_bucket` is derived from `var.target_bucket`.

You would then have to create a `main.tf` file in the root of your repository like so:

```
module "logging" {
  source = "/path/to/log_module/directory"

  // Any inputs to the module defined here
}

module "s3" {
  source = "/path/to/s3_module/directory"

  target_bucket = module.logging.bucket_id
}
```

The `main.tf` file in the root of the repository creates in implicit dependency between the `s3` and `logging` modules. The `s3` module becomes dependent on the `logging` module because the value of `target_bucket` uses the output of the `logging` module, which is the ID of the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about two modules that are contained within a parent configuration (i.e. everything is all within the same state), then @jasonwalsh has the right answer.

If you're talking about two completely separate Terraform configurations with different state files though (i.e. you run `terraform apply` on them separately), you'll want to use the [remote state data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/remote-state-data.html), combined with `outputs` in the module that is outputing values.

This allows one Terraform configuration to read output values from an entirely separate Terraform configuration, without them being children of the same parent configuration.